# Inner product of random vectors

Tags: probability-theory, vector-spaces

Suppose we have 2  vector random variables $X, Y\in \mathbb V$, $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb V$ and $Y: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb V$where $\mathbb V$ is a vector space with inner product $(X,Y)$. I have heard that the inner product of the two random vectors $X, Y$ is defined by $E(X,Y)$ which is scalar.

To define an inner product we must first have a vector space. The random variables $X,Y$ are functions, so does that mean the set of random variables  $\{X: X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb V\}$ forms a vector space? Could someone please explain this to me.

Thanks a lot.

PS. The question [Inner product and norms for random vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36781/inner-product-and-norms-for-random-vectors) is related but not exactly what I want to know.

Comment: Yes, you could verify through eight pieces of axioms of vector space.

Comment: @ShuchangZhang Is the addition defined defined for each $\omega \in \Omega$ i.e., $X(\omega)+Y(\omega)$? thanks.

Comment: Yep, it indeed :)

Comment: @ShuchangZhang Thank you. So what are the basis of that vector space?

Comment: It is a infinite dimensional vector space so basically it is very complicated to find a basis.

Comment: @ShuchangZhang Could you please provide me a reference where I read the vector space aspect of random variables? thanks.

Comment: See this [Space of random variables](http://users.aims.ac.za/~pouw/Lectures/Lecture_Spaces_Random_Variables.pdf) and it talks about how random variables are embedded in Hilbert space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of functions $\Omega \mapsto \Bbb{V}$ does in fact form a vector space in a natural way through componentwise addition and scalar multiplication.

More formally, given any two elements $X, Y \in \hom(\Omega, \Bbb{V})$, and a scalar $a\in \Bbb{R}$, we define $[X+Y](\omega) = X(\omega) + Y(\omega)$ and $[aX](\omega) = a \cdot X(\omega) $for any $\omega \in \Omega$, using the addition and scalar multiplication in $\Bbb{V}$

Comment: Does that set of functions form a Hilbert space? Thanks.

Comment: @triomphe: That depends on the original vector space, $\Bbb{V}$. If $\Bbb{V}$ is a hilbert space, then the set of functions is as well.