# What is the space of random variables equipped with the expectation inner product?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

While studying probability, I was always fascinated at how random variables seem to satisfy a host of well-known inequalities from linear algebra, such as the Cauchy Schwartz inequality. It was when I read this [article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Probability_theory) did I realize that you could define an inner product on the space of random variables.

Recall that a random variable is a function that assigns outcomes to real numbers.

Therefore, if we equip the set of random variables with the inner product taken as an expectation, i.e.,  ${\displaystyle \langle X,Y\rangle \triangleq  \operatorname {\mathbb{E}} (XY)}$, we obtain an inner product space of these functions. Observe that $\mathbb{E} (XY)$ is the correlation of $X,Y$.

It seems that this space is under-discussed in applied probability literature. Can someone elaborate if there is a name for this particular inner product space, i.e. "correlation space" ? Is this inner product space complete, i.e., a Hilbert space?

Comment: A nit-pick: Generally $E(XY)$ is not the correlation. It is the correlation if $EX=EY=0$ and $\text{Var}(X)=\text{Var}(Y)=1$.

Comment: Also you might be interested in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/36781/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the space of random variables with finite second moment: $E(X^2)<\infty$. In non-probabilistic terms, it is $L^2(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is underlying probability space that we usually don't mention when doing probability. Yes, it is a Hilbert space.

One way of using the Hilbert space structure in probability is to define conditional expectation as orthogonal projection onto the subspace of $L^2$ functions with respect to a smaller $\sigma$-algebra. A search for "Hilbert space of random variables" will bring up more.